# npm test never stops executing even all my testcases are successfully completed

Tags: mysql, node.js

Here is my config file.my tests work fine without mysql and successfully stop execution in that case but when running testcases with mysql it just get stuck over here.

name: CI

on: [push, pull_request ]

jobs:
build:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [ 14.x, 15.x ]

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Shutdown Ubuntu MySQL (SUDO)
  run: sudo service mysql stop
- name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
- name: Set up MySQL 8.0
  uses: mirromutth/mysql-action@master
  with:
    mysql version: 8.0
    mysql database: root
    mysql root password: root
    
- name: npm install, build, and test
  run: |
    npm install
    npm run build --if-present
    npm test
- name: Cancel previous runs of this workflow
  uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.6.0
  with:
      access_token: ${{ github.token }}
  env:
    CI: true
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question and explain what framework / library / runner this question is about?

Comment: If you're using mocha try adding `--exit` to the test script in package.json like this `mocha --exit`